# HTML/CSS menu bar dis miss it's shape when resizing window

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I made a menubar like picture below , Contact item is in the left of Company item , when I resize the browser Contact goes down , what is the problem?
here is picture http://oi61.tinypic.com/64h01g.jpg

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"><h1><center>Online Shopping</center></h1></div>
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Widgets</span></a></li>
     <li><a href='#'><span>Menus</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Location</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

**css**

```
body{
background:#EBEBEB;
}
#header{
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:100px;
background:#6355BD;
}
#cssmenu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 6px 0;
background: #7d7d7d url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -110px;
line-height: 100%;
border-radius: 1em;
font: normal 0.5333333333333333em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
width: auto;
}
#cssmenu li {
margin: 0 5px;
padding: 0 0 8px;
float: left;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a,
#cssmenu a:link {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
color: #e7e5e5;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 8px 20px;
margin: 0;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#cssmenu a:hover {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu .active a,
#cssmenu li:hover > a {
background: #979797 url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;
background: #666666 url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;
color: #444;
border-top: solid 1px  #f8f8f8;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
background: #7d7d7d url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -100px !important;
color: #fff !important;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 185px;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 0;
background: #ffffff url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x 0 0;
border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 3px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a,
#cssmenu ul ul a:link {
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
content: '.';
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}
* html #cssmenu ul {
  height: 1%;
}
```

Comment: I assume the problem is that because you are making the browser window smaller there is no longer any room for contact to stay on that line, thus dropping to the line below.

Comment: Yes , right but i mean why it won't be using horizontal scroll exept changing menubar shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is a problem, perfectly normal behavior. 
There is not enough space in the container, and the last element goes on second line.
If you dont want this to happen, put a min-width:400px; to #cssmenu ul. But since you have couple of ul's inside #cssmenu, better put separate class on the top one.